# How to solve circlular dependencies when deploying cloud endpoints service using cloud run in Terraform

Tags: google-cloud-functions, terraform, google-cloud-run, terraform-provider-gcp, google-cloud-endpoints-v2

I am currently trying to set up Google Cloud Endpoints on Cloud Run to be able to have an OpenApi Documentation for my Cloud Functions. I followed the instructions in [here](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/get-started-cloud-functions#deploy_endpoints_proxy) for a PoC and it worked fine.

Now I have tried to set it up using terraform 0.12.24

**Service Endpoint**

```
data "template_file" "openapi_spec" {
  template = file("../../cloud_functions/openapi_spec.yaml")

  vars = {
    endpoint_service     = local.service_name
    feedback_post_target = google_cloudfunctions_function.feedbackPOST.https_trigger_url
  }
}

resource "google_endpoints_service" "api-gateway" {
  service_name   = local.service_name
  project        = var.project_id
  openapi_config = data.template_file.openapi_spec.rendered

  depends_on = [
    google_project_service.endpoints,
    google_project_service.service-usage,
  ]
}
```

**Cloud RUN**

```
locals {
  service_name = "${var.endpoint_service_name}.endpoints.${var.project_id}.cloud.goog"
}

resource "google_cloud_run_service" "api-management" {
  name     = "api-gateway-1233"
  location = "europe-west1"

  template {
    spec {
      containers {
        image = "gcr.io/endpoints-release/endpoints-runtime-serverless:2"
        env {
          name = "ENDPOINTS_SERVICE_NAME"
          value = local.service_name
        }
      }
    }
  }
  traffic {
    percent         = 100
    latest_revision = true
  }

  depends_on = [google_project_service.run]
}
```

If I try to execute my function from the Endpoints portal now, I get the following error

```
ENOTFOUND: Error resolving domain "https://function-api-gateway.endpoints.PROJECT_ID.cloud.goog"
```

which makes total sense, as my endpoints service should use the host url of the cloud run service which is given by

```
google_cloud_run_service.api-management.status[0].url
```

which means, that I have to use this in the Service endpoints definition above as service name and host-environmental variable in the openApi definition. 
Only when this is set, I can again apply my cloud run service with the env variable being its url itself.

**This is a circular dependency which I do not know how to solve**.
Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: According to the [doc](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/get-started-cloud-run#endpoints_configure) you have to configure the End Point first and then deploy the Cloud Run you can the example in the doc.

Comment: that is exactly the circular dependency I am referring to.